# Modifier for custom Exception class (java)

Tags: java, exception, modifier

I want to define a new custom exception class in a package. What should the modifier be?
Should it be public (in case another class outside the package throws it) or should it be package-protected? What is the right practice?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how are you going to use it.
Some people create separate packages only for their custom exception classes and in that case those exceptions must be declared as `public`.

Also if you are going to use your exception in `throws` clause for `public` method in a `public` class you also need to make exception `public`.

But it also ok to make your exception package private if you are planning to use it only inside particular package.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to throw and catch it only in your package, you could make it package-protected. But I would advise to make it public, so everybody can catch your specific exception.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is make Exception class public, so can be catched by other packages, and to allow throws Exception by owner package you sets constructors in package level.